# Microchip circuit

Tags: digital-filter

I am planning to start designing circuit on microchip but do not know where to start. I will be programming some band pass filter using c++. Any advise on which microchip is better. Hope this question is relevant as i am still new to this web and circuit design thanks.
I am just new to this thing so think i have ask something none relevant or wrong question as ppl are disliking what i trying to figure out. Sorry. Will try to improve and do more research. any way thanks everyone for your help.

Comment: Make your question clearer, please. What is "designing circuit on microchip": developing code for a microcontroller? Designing a microchip? (I thought it was the latter when I saw this question), what do you have actually done and where do you want to get to?

Comment: Before i could programme my microchip i need a circuit to communicate with the microchip. Sorry have been researching on how to start using microchip. Getting very confuse here.

Comment: Which microchip? Please tell us the manufacturer and IC series.

Comment: Is there any microchip that you recommend? Still looking through and do not know which is a better micro chip. Have been told that my circuit should not be too big thus the size of the microchip have to be small.

Comment: "Which is a better micro chip?"  LM741 is just what you need to get started.  [Sorry, I couldn't resist.]

Comment: @NickAlexeev LM741 is not a programmable filter.
If he wants to program filters then better to go DSP 30F series.

Comment: u mean this? http://sg.element14.com/microchip/dspic30f2011-20i-p/16bit-mcu-dsp-20mhz-30f2011-dip18/dp/9385860

Comment: what is your definition of "microchip"? A microchip can refer to an integrated circuit, a circuit board, or even the company Microchip that designs ICs. Please do some research and clarify your question. You are unlikely to get good answers with a question like this.

Comment: Ok sorry i do not know microchip can refer to this 3 things. What i know is that it is a chip where we could programme into. Will try to go research more into it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure when you say "microchip" if you mean Microchip the company who make PICs, or micro chips (I.E. semiconductors, E.G. microcontrollers).

Assuming you mean microcontrollers in general, one nice and easy to create a band pass filter in a microcontroller is to use a [PSoC](http://www.cypress.com/?id=2232). PSoC stands for Programmable System on Chip, and it consists of: a microcontroller, reconfigurable digital and analog blocks, ADCs, Op amps, etc. You can re-configure them to perform a whole bunch of interesting things, like filtering.

Setting up the filter is pretty easy. Simply add the filter block into your design, and configure it using the dialog box:

The good thing about the filter block is that it requires *no CPU time* to operate. So you can select a relatively low power 8-bit PSoC3, and still know that the filter is performing perfectly.

[image: PSoC band pass filter]

Here I have configured it as a band pass filter, using 4 stages. As you can see, it's pretty easy to configure, and even shows you the frequency response graph.

Comment: You really like PSoC :)

Comment: @m.Alin - Yes, the moment I tried it, I was convinced. After years of using miserable PIC peripherals with their soul destroying SFRs, setting up the PSoC was *so easy*. Now I basically want everyone else in the world to use them, so we have a better community.

Comment: @m.Alin - BTW, if you want to see why the PSoC crushes all other microcontrollers, watch how it can be configured to do multiple [sensorless BLDC motor control](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=01zMZq3NHQs) *with no CPU intervention*.

Comment: @Rocketmagnet They look promising. I might give them a try :)

Comment: @m.Alin - Once you understand their power, you find yourself thinking: OMG, a PSoC could do that!

Comment: @Rocketmagnet PSoCs Rock!! I was struggling with ARM based processor for some project... and then got PSoC 3.... Configuration was fun as eating ice cream! :)

Comment: PSoC1 parts are useful but have some severe limitations. For instance, frequent interrupts can cause ADC output value corruption.

Comment: @Madmanguruman - Yeah, forget about PSoC1. 3 and 5 are the way to go. (Having said that, we still use a PSoC1 in one of our applications).